# installing multiple stores in magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento, multisite

I am having issues installing multiple sites in magento. My situation is like this. the client would like to have 3 different sites where customers from one site will not be able to log in to other sites with the same user name and password (or in other words registering at one site will not let them log into the other, they need to register separately for each site) . So I installed the main site on the main web hosting directory **mysite.com** then I installed a second store as a sub domain in **private.mysite.com** and installed in a sub directory under *“public_html”* created via a sub-domain. But after installation I am able to access the main page but unable to access the products and get 500 internal error.

can some one give me idea and suggestions on how to modify the site urls and or  .htaccess to make both sites perform independently.

Is there a better approach other than this. basically customer want to achieve 3 different stores.

one store is open for any one to buy the second store is for separate companies only and displaying their products with customers own codes, the third store is a private store where only logged in users can see the products.

the first site is a general site where as the other 2 sites are private sites sort of. Laos better if only logged in users can see the products.

Comment: Did you already try following any [guides](https://www.properhost.com/members/knowledgebase/30/How-to-Setup-Magento-with-Multiple-Stores-and-Domains.html)?

Comment: Not exactly， If some one can suggest a good guide, i am willing to try. Let me Try the One you have given here !!